# Deploying website(asp.net) to IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7

I've a website which i want to deploy on IIS 7 Server. I was able to add the website, also i've assigned an ip address (locahost's ip) and port to it as well. For example, if the port number is  8123 and ip address is say 127.0.0.1 and now, when i'm trying to view/browse my website **from remote computer** by: *http://127.0.0.1:8123* it opens a **directory page.** I'm having 3 forms in my website viz; MainPage, DashBoard and Insert. If i wish to browse to MainPage***(http://127.0.0.1:8123/MainPage.aspx)*** it gives an **runtime error** like this

Server Error in '/' Application.

> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.

```
<configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>     </system.web> </configuration>
```

I made changes as mentioned in the suggestion, however the problem still persists. Help to solve this issue. I'm new to this so i cant say i followed the right procedure, anyway everything seems good to me except the brwosing part.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 will always point at the local machine, it can not possibly access a remote site.

Comment: @StefanH i've just used 127.0.0.1 as an example in here..it differs to what i'm using...

Comment: So... what is the error?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Server Error in '/' Application..... check blockquote above. Can't browse any page shown in the directory

Comment: That isn't the error, that is just telling you an error occurred. Possibly your IIS is misconfigured. Make sure it is using the correct version of .NET. What happens when you run this locally? What happens when `<customErrors mode="Off"/>`?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev works good on local machine. Also, it gives the same when <customErrors mode="Off"/>

Comment: It probably goes to a directory page because you don't have a default page that matches up with the default page in IIS (typically a `default` or `index` file). What version of .NET is IIS set to?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev using version 4.5

Comment: Check IIS / windows logs or enable stack tracing in web.config. Can't do much without knowing what the error is.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev i think its because of the .NET version i'm using and the framework i'm selecting(in IIS,) at time of deployment. version is 4.5 and framework what i've selected is 4.0. Its saying invalid tag, referencing to targetFramework="4.5" in my aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this

```
< customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
```

and put this

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

then you can get the Error

Comment: well changed from 4.5 to 4 and added relevent assemblies and it worked